# Sending Mat Color Image from C++ to C# application through socket

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, opencv

I'm building an environment a c++ socket server and C# clients for users.

OpenCV Processing module is adopted on C++ socket server and 
C# client request Image Processing.

Of course, It would be great to use OpenCV on C# application however OpenCV dosen't support for C# so I start to make the imaging server.

I can get grayscale image through socket now but, The color Image is pretty difficult to handle it for me.  (now the buffer size is width*height*3(rgb) )

is there anyone who can give an idea to solve it?

please comment . :)

Comment: you can use C++ libs in C#, so just build a library with the functionality you need and then call it from C#. Should be doable, I have former colleagues whom did that. You basically just need to make a wrapper

Comment: But you can get the data from the Mat object (assuming you are using that), serialize it and send it

Comment: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page this is an c# wrapper for opencv